# Quais técnicas podem ser usandas para fazer autenticação em aplicações REST?

Tags: rest, autenticação, asp.net-web-api, oauth2, autenticação-http

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação `Restful` em `PHP`, preciso fazer um mecânico de autenticação nesse sistema, para que as aplicações clientes possam consumir os seus dados.

Quais técnicas podem ser usandas para fazer autenticação em sistemas `Restful`?

Comment: [Basic Authentication](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617#section-2) é um bom começo.

Comment: Geralmente eu faço da seguinte forma:
Deixo o frontend (basicamente html, css e javascript) totalmente disponível e em todos os seviços da api rest que precisam de autenticação eu implemento a verificação do Basic Authentication. Se a autenticação não for válida ou se o usuário informado não tiver permissão para acessar aquele serviço, o servidor retorna o status 401. No cliente, sempre que ocorre erro 401 o usuário é direcionado para a página de login.
Não sei se é a melhor forma. Gostaria de saber como os colegas fazem.

Comment: Já usei esse método, porem estou usando protocolo HTTP, e Basic Authentication não é seguro nesse protocolo.

Comment: Então, use HTTPS. Qualquer forma de autenticação será vulnerável em HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo que utilize o OAuth 2.0 para possibilitar o acesso dos usuários através de Tokens e garantir maior segurança ao seu usuário porque ele não precisará informar sempre o usuário e a senha como acontece no Basic Authentication, facilitará sua vida na hora de criar aplicativos móveis, além de ser o padrão utilizado por grandes marcas como Google, Facebook e PayPal.

Além desses dois métodos (OAuth2 e Basic Authentication), você pode verificar o método Digest que na minha opinião em nível de segurança está entre o Basic (que como o próprio nome diz é básico) e o OAuth2.

Recomendo também a **utilização da camada de segurança através do SSL** independente da sua escolha.

Site oficial do OAuth2 com exemplos de  de implementação: [link](http://oauth.net/2/)